# branching on program output in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been stuck on this one for a while, and looking up on help sites on how to program in batch only confuses me further.

The context is that I want to identify which files in a folder are xml valid and append all the invalid files to a specific file for further processing.

Doing so I have being using xmlstarlet and using the command below I have been able to identify which ones are valid and pipe the output to my batch file.

```
xml val *.xml | myscript.bat
```

Now, what I want to do is identify which ones are valid, in order to do so I need to parse the output of xml.exe which is the following :

```
20100319.xml - valid
20090915.xml - valid
20090915.xml - valid
20090915.xml - valid
20090915.xml - invalid
```

So what I actually need is to branch on each line to see if the last 7 characters are "invalid" or not, if yes, append the xml file to my result file.

Trying do so I built the script you'll find below.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('more') do (
 set full=%%a
 set /p prefix=!full:~-7!
 if %prefix% == "invalid" (type %%a result.xml) else (echo "valid file")
)
```

Now to be specific on my question first I get the error

```
(type was unexpected at this time.
```

Then if I remove the if branch and replace it by `echo %prefix%` I get this output :

```
- validECHO is off.
- validECHO is off.
- validECHO is off.
- validECHO is off.
invalidECHO is off.
```

Can you please help me to create a branch that will append the xml file to my result file and get rid of the ECHO is off? Turning `@ECHO off`, on, results in printing the code itself to the screen.

Thanks for your help !

Alex

Comment: You should remove the `/p` in `set /p prefix=!full:~-7!`, and you should change `if %prefix% == "invalid" (type %%a result...` to `if "!prefix!" == "invalid" ( echo %%a > result.xml ) else ( echo "valid file")`

Comment: The answer for `ECHO is off` is described at `set /?`-delayed expansion

Comment: Also, need to use the append form of redirection: `>>result.xml`

Answer (score 1):

jeb diagnosed and solved your problem in his comments (as long as you change `>result.xml` to `>>result.xml`). The Alex K. answer is good, but it will only work if you can guarantee the file names do not contain spaces.

But there is a much simpler and faster solution: Use FINDSTR to filter the results of "xml.exe", only preserving lines that end with "invalid". I think it is not a good idea to name your output file result.xml because the contents are not xml format. I renamed the output file to "invalidXML.txt".

```
xml val *.xml | findstr /e "invalid" >invalidXML.txt
```

The above assumes "xml.exe" produces valid Windows style lines that are terminated with `<CR><LF>`. If this is not the case and "xml.exe" produces unix style lines terminated with `<Lf>`, then use MORE to convert to Windows style.

```
xml val *.xml | more | findstr /e "invalid" >invalidXML.txt
```

To get a list of valid files you can use (again add MORE if needed)

```
xml val *.xml | findstr /e "- valid" >validXML.txt
```

The above preserves the "- invalid" or "- valid" indicator at the end of each line, as does your original code (once debugged). And it works without needing a batch file :)

If you want output like what Alex K. suggested (file names only), then you are back to using a FOR loop, best within a batch file. I migrated the xml.exe validation into the FOR loop. You can revert to piping the results into the batch if you want. This solution will work even if there are spaces in the file name. I used `EOL=:` just in case a filename starts with `;`, highly unlikely, but possible.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('xml val *.xml') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  if "!ln:~-7!" == "invalid" (>>invalidXML.txt echo !ln:0,~-10!) else echo !ln:0,~-8! is valid
)
```

If a file name contains `!`, then the name will be corrupted by `set "ln=%%A"` due to delayed expansion. The fix is to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('xml val *.xml') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if "!ln:~-7!" == "invalid" (>>invalidXML.txt echo !ln:0,~-10!) else echo !ln:0,~-8! is valid
  end local
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the patterns is "`FILENAME - RESULT`" you can use the `FOR` loop to split on a white space such that `%%a=FILENAME`, `%%B=-` and `%%C=RESULT`

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%a in ('more') do (
    if "%%c" neq "valid" (
        echo %%a is invalid [%%c]
        echo %%a >> result.xml
    ) else (
        echo %%a is valid
    )
)
```

Not sure about `type %%a result.xml`, I don't think that's a valid command.

`echo %%a >> result.xml` will append the file name to result.xml

Comment: This answer assumes none of the file names contain spaces. It will fail for any name that does contain a space.